# How can I position a number in between two numbers on a horizontal line?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I cannot wrap my head around this kind of design. What is a good approach?

I am receiving the 3 numbers dynamically: min, max and something in between.

How can I determine where to place the middle number and also how can I design this?

I have only found something like NoUiSlider but I don't need a slider.

What I have done so far is to add div's to make this look somehow similar but it does not feel correct.

I am happy with any hints.

Thank you!

PS I know the image is not 100% correct with the pips.

[image: The Design I want to achieve]

---

**EDIT 1**

I have got a solution inspired by the other answer:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
  
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 0px;
  width: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

datalist {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

datalist option {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  top: 25px;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2px;
}

datalist option:first-of-type {
  border-left: 0;
}

datalist option:last-of-type {
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="range-2">
    <datalist id="custom-list-2">
      <option value="1" style="background: #fff;">4</option>
      <option value="2"></option>
      <option value="3" style="background: #f07d00;
    color: #fff;border:none;padding:2px;">5</option>
      <option value="4"></option>
      <option value="5" style="background: #fff;">5</option>
    </datalist>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" list="custom-list-2"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will determine in another progra the position left, middle or right for the given number in between. So this way of representation is nice enough.

And to all those people crying for more input of myself: as I have stated I literally had no clue how to approach this that is why I asked it here. But the community becomes more and more unfriendly with people of less knowledge..

---

**EDIT 2**

I have done another one looking now exactly like requested:
https://jsfiddle.net/24d18wa9/

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Here what  came up with. I am sure you can make the rest.

What I have done here is to make two spans for each MIN and MAX value. I later get the value of these spans. In between there is a div acting as a slider. In the slider there is an indicator that will point out the result.

You then get the value of the input compare it to its MIN value,  so we know how much to shift. And from here its basic math and comparison.

```js
var maxSpan = document.getElementById('max')
var minSpan = document.getElementById('min')
var sliderSpan = document.getElementById('slider')
var input = document.getElementById('value')
var differenceInValue = maxSpan.innerHTML - minSpan.innerHTML
var sliderWidth = sliderSpan.offsetWidth

function myFunc() {
  var inputValue = input.value
  var inputPercent = inputValue - (+minSpan.innerHTML)
  var calculatePosition = calculatePos(inputPercent, sliderWidth, differenceInValue)
  document.getElementById('indicator').style.left = calculatePosition + 'px'
}

function calculatePos(x, y, z) {
  return (x * y) / z
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: beige;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

#indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span id="min">4</span>
  <div class="slider" id="slider">
    <div id="indicator">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <span id="max">6</span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="value" onchange="myFunc()">
```

Comment: Hi, a code-only answer can be made more useful with some description of how it works. Also, a minor point, but using const and let instead of var can be helpful in insuring the scope of a constant or variable is correct.

Comment: hello, yes I will add a description , and thank you for your note , i will Keep in mind to use "Const" more often

Comment: I see no reason to remove the commented lines, i think they improve the Answer.You demand description yet you edit the code so its less understandable?

Comment: I did not edit your code - I just suggested that you add a verbal description. You can check who has edited your code and who has commented - make sure they are the same person!

Comment: I know, Their name is written next to mine. Iam sorry if i offended you

Comment: Ah, good ole English "you" vs "you".

Comment: Thanks you very much. I have come up with a solution inspired by your approach. Thanks! See original post with the code.